# Starting Android app from browser: How to feature-detect "Intent" support?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, android-intent

We are trying to build an parameterized entry webpage for our app in which about 50% of users will have our app installed, 50% not.

Originally, we had been using a specialized URL scheme that our app had registered; ie,

myapp://dothing?specialParameters=5

However, we have difficulty detecting cases where users either don't have our app installed, or have an earlier version of our app that doesn't support URL schemes. In Chrome, or the Android Browser, the user is navigated to a browser-generated Error page since it couldn't locate the server.

In iOS Safari, and Android Firefox, we can resolve this through the use of a setTimeout before navigation;

```
function timeoutFn() {
            var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = //iOS Appstore location;
            }, 1000);
            window.addEventListener("pagehide", function(evt) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            });

            window.location = "myApp://dothing?specialParameters=5";
        }
```

My solution for Chrome/Android Browser is to use Google's recommended system of Intents, described here:
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents

I've tested this out, and it actually seems to work well - however, Firefox does not know how to handle links beginning with "intent://". We can still use the above JavaScript function for Firefox, but I'm very reluctant to start writing user-agent-sniffing code for it, especially since I'd think it likely any other web browsers on Android will similarly lack Intent support.

So, back to the title question: Chrome, and the Android browser, are capable of opening apps through "intent://" links - is there any way, using JavaScript or similar methods, to use feature detection to find this support?

Answer (score 0):

This is what we are currently using, however, it's far from ideal ...

```
function isItentsSupported() {
    var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
    if (isChrome) {
        var version = parseInt(window.navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome\/(\d+)\./)[1], 10);
        return version >= 25; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Chrome version number based on [Google documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

Comment: So, the Google spec is to use user agent sniffing. I think each incident makes Microsoft look far more web-open by comparison...

Comment: No, the spec doesnt say to do use agent sniffing (I have updated my answer to make it clearer). I couldn't find any other way to detect if intents are supported.